# Links in comments

Tags: support, comments

Is it possible to pretty up links in comments?  Similar to the way we can in answers.  [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments) says no. I'm unsuccessful finding an answer for meta-Programmers.

Comment: [Test](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments)

Comment: [Test2](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments)

Comment: This is a [test](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments).

Comment: [This works](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You mean automatically convert a link to the question title? No, that's not possible.

You can, however, use the markdown syntax to do it manually:

`[Links in comments](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments)` => [Links in comments](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments)

Comment: +1 Thanks, I've been wanting to know this for the longest time.